# Has many belongs_to is not working Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

This is a very noob question, I am starting with Rails. I have a class User that has many Rates and each rates belongs to a user.

Rate Class

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User Class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authenticable

  has_many :rates

  validates :username, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true, allow_nil: true
```

Migration of Rates

```
class CreateRates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rates do |t|
      t.string :points

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Migration of User

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: true,  default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      t.string   :authentication_token,   default: ""

      ## User attributes
      t.string   :username,               default: ""

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :authentication_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

When I create the database and run rake db:migrate, all entity are migrated ok but the table rate has not user_id

Comment: Please check if your migration file for Rate defines the field user_id. If not, create a new migration file and add user_id to rates table and run db:migrate again.

Comment: As far as migrations go, the models are irrelevant - it's entirely down to what is in your migrations.

Comment: Can you include the code for your migrations that add `user_id`? That's likely the source of your problem.

Comment: I added the migrations, I have never added the user_id to the migration rates, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add user_id column to rates table

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the migration files themselves, but you can use the `add_reference` function in your migrations to add a reference to a table:

```
class AddUserIdToRate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    unless column_exists? :rates, :user_id
      add_reference :rates, :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

If you get an error, post it here and we can hopefully provide more information.

**Edit**

There's nothing in your migrations involving the creation of a `user_id` column on your `rates` table. Adding a migration with the above code should add the `user_id` foreign key.